# d3 map color to something other than value because colors are being duplicated when values are equal

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When the values in the array are equal to one another, the colors will be the same. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/featherita/8SkG9/1/

And this is what I want it to do even if the values are equal:

http://jsfiddle.net/featherita/8SkG9/

It is happening on the stacked bar that makes the y axis and on the pie charts to the left because I'm filling the values with a color array.

If you set bottom and top = to one another, they will both take on the first color of the array.

```
"threshRange":[{ "bottom": 6, "middle": 4, "top": 7 }],
```

If you set the first and last values in SiteStatus.slice = to one another, they will also render the same color.

```
"slice":[16,84] *** in the first node and "slice":[16,84] *** in the last node
```

This is causing problems when data is automatically delivered, is there a better way to set this up so they always take on the next color in the array, green, yellow, red?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. How do you want your example to be different?

Comment: I want to be able to enter in the same value and have it use 2 different colors so if this were the case "threshRange":[{ "bottom": 6, "middle": 4, "top": 6 }], it would still render green, yellow, red. Does that help?

Comment: Here is an example of what it does when values are equal: http://jsfiddle.net/featherita/8SkG9/1/

Comment: You could use the index of the (in this case parent) element to determine the fill -- http://jsfiddle.net/8SkG9/2/ Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you!! if you want to repost this I'll happily flag it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the index of the (in this case parent) element instead of the value to determine the fill:

```
.style("fill", function (d, i, j) { return color(j); });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8SkG9/2/).